# Receives System.Byte[] in GridView when MySql's DateFormat Function is used

Tags: asp.net, mysql, gridview

I have written this query for retrieving data from mysql as below

```
select FeedbackCode,EMailID,FeedbackDetail,
       Date_Format(FeedbackDate,'%m,%d') as 'Feedback_Date'
from FeedbackDetail
where EMailID not like '' and InstanceCode =5
```

and I'm binding this data with GridView in asp.net but at the column of Feedback_Date,
instead of Date I receive `System.Byte[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the connector. Try:

```
CAST(Date_Format(FeedbackDate,'%m,%d') AS CHAR(20))
```