# Triggers sql(change type column)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf, datagrid

i need select data, end i need change column `date_payment` with `DateTime` to `Text`, please help...

i write this query

```
SELECT r.id, user_name, user_phone, date_create, REPLACE( date_payment,  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  'No payment' ) , payment_method, amount, rs.name_ru
FROM request AS r, request_status AS rs
WHERE r.status = rs.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

in sql console query is valid, and `date_payment` is replase, but:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        GetList();

        source.DataSource = dt;
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = source;
```

then column(date_payment) in datagrid is null - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculated column doesn't have any name. Add "AS updated_date_payment" keyword and request "updated_date_payment" column in your program:

```
SELECT r.id, user_name, user_phone, date_create, REPLACE( date_payment,  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  'No payment' ) AS updated_date_payment, payment_method, amount, rs.name_ru
FROM request AS r, request_status AS rs
WHERE r.status = rs.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543182/receives-system-byte-in-gridview-when-mysqls-dateformat-function-is-used

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
SELECT r.id, user_name, user_phone, date_create, REPLACE( date_payment,  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  'No payment' ) AS date_payment, payment_method, amount, rs.name_ru
FROM request AS r, request_status AS rs
WHERE r.status = rs.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here you have to use ***AS*** keyword. Otherwise it will return the column name for *REPLACE( date_payment,  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  'No payment' )* as *(no column name)*